# How to read html body from web-site using Python version 3x

Tags: python

I would like to connect and receive http response from a specific web site link.
I have many Python codes  :

```
import urllib.request
import os,sys,re,datetime

fp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.python.org")
mybytes = fp.read()

mystr = mybytes.decode(encoding=sys.stdout.encoding)
fp.close()
```

when I pass the response as a parameter to:
 `BeautifulSoup(str(mystr), 'html.parser')`
 to get the cleaned html text, I got the following error:

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25bc' in position 1139: character maps to <undefined>.
```

The question how can I solve this problem?

**complete code :**

```
import urllib.request
import os,sys,re,datetime
fp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.python.org")
mybytes = fp.read()

mystr = mybytes.decode(encoding=sys.stdout.encoding)
fp.close()


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(mystr), 'html.parser')
mystr = soup;
print(mystr.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is perfectly happy to consume the file-like object returned by `urlopen`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with urlopen("...") as website:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: No, it does not work,
So Please try yourself before answering!

    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xdc' in position 18136: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my computer using `"http://www.python.org"` instead of `"..."`

Comment: No, I did that,
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25bc' in position 7846: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Just tested your original code as well, works like a charm too. Your problem has nothing to do with reading html from website (read neither `urllib.request` nor `BeautifulSoup`) but with your system. Something wrong with your locale/default encoding here.

Comment: how can i change locale/default encoding/coding in python

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `requests` library you can avoid these complications:)

```
import requests
fp = requests.get("http://www.python.org")
mystr = fp.text

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(mystr, 'html.parser')
mystr = soup;
print(mystr.get_text())
```

Comment: Not work still have the same problem, Please check before answering. 

 return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25bc' in position 1139: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I did check my code, which runs on my computer, but now that I checked your code I see that it also runs on my computer.  That may mean that the problem is not in your code.  You may want to check that all your software is updated and see if that helps.